# Attaching extra information to model instance - django

Tags: python, django

I have a django model that I want to attach an extra piece of information to, depending on the environment the instance is in (which user is logged in). For this reason, I don't want to do it at the database level.

Is this okay to do? Or are there problems that I don't foresee?

**in models.py**

```
class FooOrBar(models.Model):
    """Type is 'foo' or 'bar'
    """
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type
```

**in views.py**

```
class FooCheck(FooOrBar):
    """Never saved to the database
    """
    def __init__(self, foo_or_bar):
        self.__dict__ = foo_or_bar.__dict__.copy()

    def check_type(self, external_type):
        if external_type == 'foo':
            self.is_foo = True
        else:
            self.is_foo = False


foos_or_bars = FooOrBar.objects.all()
foochecks = map(FooCheck, foos_or_bars)
for foocheck in foochecks:
    foocheck.check_type('foo')
```

extra credit question: Is there a more efficient way of calling a method on multiple objects i.e. replacing the last forloop with something clever?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check a user's relation to a model when rendering to a template - Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029140/how-to-check-a-users-relation-to-a-model-when-rendering-to-a-template-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this does not work. Trying to delete a `FooOrBar` objects throws a complaint about

```
OperationalError at /

no such table: test_FooCheck
```

To get around this I'm just not going to inherit from FooOrBar, but if anyone has a suggestion on a better way to do it I'd be interested in hearing it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I did something like:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    # specific info goes here

class Bar(models.Model):
    # specific info goes here

class FooBar(models.Model):
    CLASS_TYPES = {
        "foo":Foo,
        "bar":Bar
    }
    type = models.CharField(choices=CLASS_TYPES)
    id = models.IntegerField()

    #field to identify FooBar
```

then you can get the object back using

```
object = FooBar.CLASS_TYPES[instance.type].objects.get(id=instance.id)
```

where `instance` is the FooBar instance