# How to check a user's relation to a model when rendering to a template - Django

Tags: django

For example, the voting feature for a stackoverflow question.

```
if user has voted:
    highlight arrow
```

if the model is set up like so:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    #....
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Is it best to do something like

views.py

```
class DisplayQuestion:
    def __init__(self, question, user):
        self.__dict__ = question.__dict__.copy()
        self.has_voted = user in question.voters.all()

def show_question(request, question_pk):
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_pk)
    render('question.html', {'question':DisplayQuestion(question, request.user)})
```

or pass it as another variable?

```
def show_question(request, question_pk):
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_pk)
    render('question.html', {'question':question, 
                             'has_voted':user in question.voters.all()})
```

This seems less ideal. You might want to display a whole bunch of questions, and not pass a `has_voted` for each one.

or is the best way to check via an ajax() call?

Comment: I can't see the point of the QuestionDisplay class at all. If you want a `has_voted` attribute, just add it directly to each `question` instance. Remember, Python objects are dynamic.

Comment: @DanielRoseman do you mean as a `model.BooleanField` ?

Comment: No, not as a field at all. At an attribute that you annotate at runtime.

Comment: So just `question.has_voted = user in question.voters.all()` yeah.... that's a waaay better way of doing it. Please submit an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to just annotate an attribute before sending to the template.

```
question.has_voted = user in question.voters.all()
```